# how to solve a error "Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data." while saving a data in checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, checkout-page

how to solve an error

> Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data.

while saving a data in checkout  page in Magento 2

[image: magento]

Comment: Do you make any customization on shipping or checkout ?

Comment: S i added a custom attributes in checkout page

Comment: May be your custom attribute not working properly so can you please rollback your changes and check again ?

Comment: when revert the etc/di.xml and Plugin/Magento/Quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php file its working but i need to save a customer attributes

Comment: i used  [this blog](https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/) done a customer attributes

Comment: You can check in var/log/system.log or var/log/exception.log there you can find something which will help you debug the issue.

Comment: I am experiencing for specific customer only. When logged in with that user it throws this error. Any luck with anyone?